# How can I re-enable bonus powers in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I played through the game and all its dlc-s back in the days...and now I have the Citadel DLC which I'm playing. My problem is that after reinstalling ME3 it reset my DLC-s so I can play through Omega (and the others) again. This means that I don't have the "Flare" power anymore because I can get it from Aria.

So how can I hack my game to get that power? I know about Gibbed's editor and coalesced.bin but I was not able to do so so far.

I know about [this wiki page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#Temporarily_Adding_Any_Power) but the suggestions for "unlocking bonus powers" is no good because in the mentioned array there is no power named "Flare"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gibbed's Save Editor go to:

Raw -> 3. Squad -> Player -> Powers. Open the collection and replace a current power by changing the Class Name and Name or add a power by clicking "Add". In Class Name type "sfxgamecontentdlc_exp_pack002.SFXPowerCustomAction_BioticFlare" (without quotation marks), under Name type "Flare" (without quotation marks). And you're good to go.

If you already have 8 powers it might give you an issue to add Flare as a 9th instead of replacing one because the weapon wheel only allows for 8.